# Polling using Select function in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, sockets, polling, receiver

I am new in `Socket Programming`. I am trying to create a Application that uses `Sockets` for Communication.

I have doubt in the Receive function because sometime it just hangs in `recvfrom` function.
I am using `select` function for polling. It works when Camera is connected but If I remove Camera it doesn't show the Error Message.

**My Code for Polling:**

```
FD_ZERO(&m_readFds);
FD_SET(Sock, &m_readFds);

m_timeInterval.tv_usec = 30;            //30 Microseconds for Polling
m_socketLength = sizeof(m_cameraInfo);

m_lastBlockId = -1;

while (m_acquiringThreadStatus)
{
    FD_CLR(Sock, &m_readFds);
    FD_SET(Sock, &m_readFds);

    m_receivingStatus = select(Sock + 1, &m_readFds, NULL, NULL, &m_timeInterval);
    if (m_receivingStatus < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No Data to Receive"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((m_receivedBytes = recvfrom(Sock, m_packetBuffer, RECEIVING_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&m_cameraInfo, &m_socketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"Data Received"<<std::endl;
        }
     }
}
```

An one more question is that when I continously printing the `Data Received` Statement after sometime  It stop. So how can I increase the size of Socket `Receiving Buffer`.

Thanks in Advance

**Edit**

```
SOCKET m_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if(m_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
// Error
}
else
{
//In the else part bind the socket 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read `select()`'s documentation, you would see that `select()` returns -1 on error, 0 on timeout, and > 0 on requested event(s).  However, that is not how you are treating the return value. You are treating -1 as timeout and >= 0 as data events.  So, you end up calling `recvfrom()` when there is nothing available to read.  If the socket is in blocking mode (its default mode), `recvfrom()` will block the calling thread until data is actually available.

Try this instead:

```
m_lastBlockId = -1;

while (m_acquiringThreadStatus)
{
    FD_ZERO(&m_readFds);
    FD_SET(Sock, &m_readFds);

    m_timeInterval.tv_sec = 0;
    m_timeInterval.tv_usec = 30; //30 Microseconds for Polling

    m_receivingStatus = select(Sock + 1, &m_readFds, NULL, NULL, &m_timeInterval);

    if (m_receivingStatus == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    if (m_receivingStatus == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No Data to Receive" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    m_socketLength = sizeof(m_cameraInfo);
    if ((m_receivedBytes = recvfrom(Sock, m_packetBuffer, RECEIVING_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&m_cameraInfo, &m_socketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    std::cout << "Data Received" << std::endl;
}
```

As for the size of the socket's receive buffer, you can set it via `setsockopt()` using the `SO_RCVBUF` option, eg:

```
int bufsize = ...;
setsockopt(Sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&bufsize, sizeof(bufsize));
```

Comment: why 0 in Select function?

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala something in the original question made me think originally that the code was targeting Winsock, which ignores the 1st parameter of `select()`. But re-reading the question again, I don't see what made me think that, so I have replaced the 0 with `Sock + 1`, which is required on non-Windows platforms.

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala the only way that can happen is if the socket is not receiving any data. And FWIW, 30 **microseconds** is a VERY short timeout to use for a socket. Honestly, at that small a time, I would just get rid of `select()` and let `recvfrom()` block until data arrives. Optionally using `SO_RCVTIMEO` to timeout a blocking read. If you are going to use `select()`, a much larger timeout is generally preferred (on the order of **seconds** instead) and break the loop when no data is being received, so you don't hang your app indefinitely

Comment: Wireshark showing that camera is sending packets. I am using 57181 port. First I think it is because of firewall but I turn off the firewall but still I am getting the timeout even if I replace m_timeInterval.tv_sec = 0 to 1

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala then you are likely not setting up the socket correctly. Please show your actual code that creates the socket before entering the `select` loop.