# Why should FD_ISSET() judge before accept（）establishes a connection

Tags: c, sockets

Today I just learned the socket's `select()`. The information found on the Internet directly says that `FD_ISSET()` judges whether **fd** is available, and if it is available, `accept()` establishes a connection.

But there is no explanation why it is not possible to establish a connection with `accept()` first, and then use `FD_ISSET()` to determine whether **fd** is available?

My guess is that using `accept()` to establish a connection will consume more resources than use `FD_ISSET()` to determine whether **fd** is available.

Comment: Do you want to (1) see whether there is a connection waiting, and then (2) get it? Or do you want to (1) wait for a connection to appear and then (2) see whether there is another one?

Answer (score 2):

For a listening socket, the socket should be part of the `read_fds`. `select()` will then wake up if the listening socket is readable. `select()` will return the subset of `read_fds` that are actually readable.

If the listening socket is part of that subset, then it is readable, which indicates a new connection is ready to be accepted. For TCP, this typically means the 3 way handshake has completed. So, `accept()` on the listening socket will return a new socket to represent the new connection.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux man pages describes the `select()` function https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html in this way:

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

> select() allows a program to monitor multiple file descriptors,
> waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for
> some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file
> descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform a
> corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2), or a sufficiently small
> write(2)) without blocking.

The goal of `select()` is to allow you to test whether one or more sockets are ready for an action or not. The `timeout` parameter allows you to specify how long to wait for any of the sockets to be ready. So this is a synchronous call in that you call the function and it will either return when one or more of the sockets are ready for an action or, if a time out value was specified, when the time out has expired.

> On success, select() and pselect() return the number of file
> descriptors contained in the three returned descriptor sets (that is,
> the total number of bits that are set in readfds, writefds,
> exceptfds).  The return value may be zero if the timeout expired
> before any file descriptors became ready.
>
> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error; the
> file descriptor sets are unmodified, and timeout becomes undefined.

You specify which sockets are to be checked by the `select()` by specifying a map using the `FD_SET()` macro.  See [Socket programming in C, using the select() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372605/socket-programming-in-c-using-the-select-function) as well as [Polling using Select function in C++ on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854161/polling-using-select-function-in-c-on-windows) and [Is it necessary to reset the fd_set between select system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563577/is-it-necessary-to-reset-the-fd-set-between-select-system-call) for examples.

If you have more than one socket set in a mask or are using multiple masks with sockets set then when the `select()` function returns indicating that one or more sockets are ready, you need to use the `FD_ISSET()` macro to determine which of the sockets you have requested a status on are actually ready.

However if you have specified only a single socket in only one of the masks then when the `select()` returns indicating a sockets is ready, you only have one socket that could be ready.

The reason for using the `FD_ISSET()` anyway is just as a check no matter what. Think of it as good programming practice as well as improving robustness of the source code in the face of maintenance which may add other sockets in the future.

If you call `accept()` with a blocking listening socket and there is not a connection waiting to be accepted then the thread is going to block on the `accept()` until a connection request is received. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html

> If no pending connections are present on the queue, and the socket is
> not marked as nonblocking, accept() blocks the caller until a
> connection is present.  If the socket is marked nonblocking and no
> pending connections are present on the queue, accept() fails with the
> error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.
>
> In order to be notified of incoming connections on a socket, you can
> use select(2), poll(2), or epoll(7).  A readable event will be
> delivered when a new connection is attempted and you may then call
> accept() to get a socket for that connection.  Alternatively, you can
> set the socket to deliver SIGIO when activity occurs on a socket; see
> socket(7) for details.

Since you are using `select()` to check if the listening socket is ready the most probably having `accept()` block is not the behavior you desire so using `FD_ISSET()` first before calling `accept()` seems the most prudent course of action.

Answer (score 0):

> Today I just learned the socket's `select()`. The information found on
> the Internet directly says that `FD_ISSET()` judges whether **fd** is
> available, and if it is available, `accept()` establishes a
> connection.

"whether **fd** is available" is a rather poor way to word it, and perhaps that is contributing to your confusion.  Having called `select()` with arguments expressing an interest in reading file descriptor **fd**, `FD_ISSET()` can tell you whether **fd** is ready to be read (without blocking).  For the file descriptor representing a listening socket, "ready to be read" means that there is a pending connection waiting to be accepted.

> But there is no explanation why it is not possible to establish a
> connection with `accept()` first, and then use `FD_ISSET()` to
> determine whether **fd** is available?

You seem to have missed the point of using `select()`, which is to avoid blocking on I/O operations such as `accept()`.

One certainly can call `accept()` on a file descriptor without first using `select()` and `FD_ISSET()` to determine that there is a connection waiting to be accepted.  In that event, if **fd** is an open file descriptor representing a listening socket then `accept()` will *block* until it can accept a connection, or until it is interrupted for some other reason.  This can be a perfectly reasonable thing to do, but it is exactly what you are trying to avoid doing by applying `select()` to the problem.

In any event, `FD_ISSET()` is not useful after you have already accepted a connection (until you check again with `select()`), *because you already accepted a connection*.  If `FD_ISSET()` reports at that point that the file descriptor is in the set then that information is stale.  Otherwise, it is merely moot.

> My guess is that using `accept()` to establish a connection will
> consume more resources than use `FD_ISSET()` to determine whether
> **fd** is available.

That is likely true, but it is irrelevant.  The whole point of using `select()` for something like this is not to save computational cost but rather to avoid blocking.  Typically, that is used to allow a single thread to manage multiple I/O channels efficiently, but it can also be used to perform other kinds of work in between handling I/O.